# appium safari ios gives error: The environment unavailable

Tags: appium

I run `appium` iphone test with command `mocha ios-safari.js` and it gives error:

**The environment you requested was unavailable**

Where `ios-safari.js` is example downloaded from [`appium samples`](https://github.com/appium/sample-code/tree/master/sample-code/examples/node):

```
"use strict";

require("./helpers/setup");

var wd = require("wd"),
    _ = require('underscore'),
    serverConfigs = require('./helpers/appium-servers');

describe("ios safari", function () {
  this.timeout(300000);
  var driver;
  var allPassed = true;

  before(function () {
    var serverConfig = process.env.SAUCE ?
      serverConfigs.sauce : serverConfigs.local;
    driver = wd.promiseChainRemote(serverConfig);
    require("./helpers/logging").configure(driver);

    var desired = _.clone(require("./helpers/caps").ios81);
    desired.browserName = 'safari';
    if (process.env.SAUCE) {
      desired.name = 'ios - safari';
      desired.tags = ['sample'];
    }
    return driver.init(desired);
  });

  after(function () {
    return driver
      .quit()
      .finally(function () {
        if (process.env.SAUCE) {
          return driver.sauceJobStatus(allPassed);
        }
      });
  });

  afterEach(function () {
    allPassed = allPassed && this.currentTest.state === 'passed';
  });


  it("should get the url", function () {
    return driver
      .get('https://www.google.com')
      .sleep(1000)
      .waitForElementByName('q', 5000)
        .sendKeys('sauce labs')
        .sendKeys(wd.SPECIAL_KEYS.Return)
      .sleep(1000)
      .title().should.eventually.include('sauce labs');
  });

  it("should delete cookie passing domain and path", function () {
    var complexCookieDelete = function(name, path, domain) {
      return function() {
        path = path || '|';
        return driver.setCookie({name: name, value: '', path: path, 
          domain: domain, expiry: 0});        
      };
    };

    return driver
      .get('http://en.wikipedia.org')
      .waitForElementByCss('.mediawiki', 5000)
      .allCookies() // 'GeoIP' cookie is there
      .deleteCookie('GeoIP') 
      .allCookies() // 'GeoIP' is still there, because it is set on
                    // the .wikipedia.org domain
      .then(complexCookieDelete('GeoIP', '/', '.wikipedia.org'))
      .allCookies() // now 'GeoIP' cookie is gone
      .sleep(1000);
  });

});
```

The `appium` log is the following:

```
info: [debug] Error: Could not find a device to launch. You requested 

'iPhone 6 (8.1 Simulator)', 

but the available devices were: [
"iPad 2 (8.3 Simulator) [2F86D724-B8D6-4F22-B5E8-97B437C9ACFB]",
"iPad Air (8.3 Simulator) [8A07B826-AF59-4FC4-BC8E-21B37ADAF539]",
"iPad Retina (8.3 Simulator) [9C589CB6-1CF4-437E-83DB-1270DB1599FC]",
"iPhone 4s (8.3 Simulator) [31F567A4-5346-4E1A-B414-C45062105964]",
"iPhone 5 (8.3 Simulator) [E820B152-B5B4-4A79-B9DE-3A1F49859662]",
"iPhone 5s (8.3 Simulator) [5A07EBE7-264A-4571-BA9E-1F17C882ADE3]",

"iPhone 6 (8.3 Simulator) [58856942-BD3F-45C6-9B1B-93102851B37E]",

"iPhone 6 Plus (8.3 Simulator)
```

Since I recenlty have updated `X code` to last version seemingly I should change device name somewhere in config from `iPhone 6 (8.1 Simulator)` to `iPhone 6 (8.3 Simulator) [58856942-BD3F-45C6-9B1B-93102851B37E]`. But where exactly should I do this - cannot figure out.

Answer (score 0):

You specify the target device when you start an Appium session.  On the command line, use '--device-name' parameter.  In the Appium UI, you specify which device you want there in the iOS tab.  I've found it to be a bit finicky about the name.  I've had the most success being as general as necessary to differentiate between devices.  IOW, try 'iPhone 6' or 'iPhone 5 (8.3 simulator)' instead of the entire string.

Comment: I run `Appium UI` and there is no selection for device name in iOS tab. Could your write down full string how to run `Appium` from a console with `--device-name`?